# Can I have 'local root' accounts inside a VirtualBox guest OS?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, root

Do you know if I can get a local 'root' inside a VirtualBox guest OS (Linux)?

I need this to install the "guest extensions". Should this be the same as my "host" OS root?

Answer (score 1):

The user accounts on a virtual machine have no connection to those from the hosting operating system.

When you need to [install guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp55744480) with root permissions, then you need to have root permissions on the virtual machine. You can do that by

- creating (or logging into) the `root` user account there, or
- running `sudo` commands as a privileged user (if the Linux distribution does not have `root` accounts by default)